# While - Retorna apenas um registro

Tags: php

Porque meu WHILE está exibindo apenas um registro (são dois registros!)

```
$resultnome = mysql_query("
select DIVU.DIVU_NM_DIVULGACAO, DIVU.DIVU_DS_LOGRADOURO, DIVU.DIVU_DS_NUMERO, DIVU.DIVU_DS_TELEFONES, DIVU.ID_PRESTADOR_DIVULGACAO, SERVI.SERV_NM_SERVICO, TISE.ID
from DIVULGACAO DIVU 
LEFT JOIN SERVICO SERVI ON DIVU.ID = SERVI.ID_DIVULGACAO
LEFT join TIPO_SERVICO TISE ON SERVI.ID_TIPO_SERVICO = TISE.ID
WHERE DIVU.DIVU_NM_DIVULGACAO = 'MeuTexto' AND TISE.ID = 3
") or die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultnome);
$nomeunidade = $rows['DIVU_NM_DIVULGACAO'];
$enderecounidade = $rows['DIVU_DS_LOGRADOURO'];
$numerounidade = $rows['DIVU_DS_NUMERO'];
$telefoneunidade = $rows['DIVU_DS_TELEFONES'];

echo '<strong>'.$nomeunidade.'</strong><br>';

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultnome))
  {
    echo $rows['SERV_NM_SERVICO'];
  }

echo '<br><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> '.$enderecounidade.', '.$numerounidade.'<br>';
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Tel. '.$telefoneunidade.'<br>';
```

Comment: Poderia postar uma saída da variável `$resultespecialidade`? ela retorna em `array` ?

Comment: O que podes fazer é retornar em forma de objeto e usar o `foreach` para mostrar.

Comment: O Poste a saída da variável `$resultnome`, poste na pergunta que fica mais fácil de entender.

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta... deixei mais objetivo.

Comment: Você tem dois `mysql_fetch_array`, um deles antes do `while`. Esse primeiro avança o ponteiro para o segundo registro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você já está utilizando a função `mysql_fetch_array` antes do laço de repetição, ou seja, você já obteve um registro, e o `while` irá começar no segundo. Uma solução simples é utilizar o `do...while`:

```
do {
    echo $rows['SERV_NM_SERVICO'];
} while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultnome));
```

Vale lembrar que só é possível utilizar esta solução pois você já está obtendo o primeiro resultado antes do laço de repetição.

Comment: Obrigado Oeslei.
Já imagina qual era o motivo do problema, mas mesmo assim não estava vendo uma solução... Obrigado resolvido.